# How to read from a file and fill an arraylist?

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist

I have an arraylist of employees and I want to sort them according to their salaries, the program should read from a file each line contains some info of one employee. The problem is that I should use cloneable interface while sorting the array but it just doesn't work with me.. Can anyone help please?

Following the sort method:

```
public static ArrayList<Worker> sort(ArrayList<Worker> _workers) throws CloneNotSupportedException{
    Worker temp;
    for (int i=0;i<_workers.size();i++){
        if ((_workers.get(i)).compareTo(_workers.get(i+1))==1){
            temp=(Worker) _workers.get(i).clone();
            _workers.set(i, _workers.get(i+1));
            _workers.set(i+1, temp);    
        }
    }
    return _workers;
}
```

Following the clone method(I repeated it in each of the subclasses):

```
public SalariedEmployee clone() throws  CloneNotSupportedException{
    SalariedEmployee objClone=new SalariedEmployee();
    objClone.setIdNumber(this.getIdNumber());
    objClone.setName(this.getName());
    objClone.setHours(this.getHours());
    objClone.setHourRate(this.getHourRate());
    return objClone;
}
```

Comment: Did you just copy/pasted your homework? this is not the place to ask for code, please show some effort.

Comment: I'm not asking for the code.. I need to know how to use the cloneable interface in sorting the arraylist

Comment: It seems you already have tried something. Add what you tried so far (*why* did your own code not work?) and the question could be re-opened. Also add a tag for your programming language.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using the clone method properly.

Comment: You need a blank line before the code block or it won't show up as code. Used the `{}` tool from the toolbar, that indents four spaces and adds any necessary blank lines for you. Also, formatting works better here if you convert your tabs to spaces.

Comment: You should add/explain what *doesn't work* means. Do you get a compile error or does it fail at runtime and if so how. What is the result you get on your input and what did you expect?

Comment: I have a runtime error it prints "[]" just, the input is read from a file the file consists of lines each line represents the info of a specific employee whether they're hourly,weekly or temporary employee and their name,their id and their salary, then it should sort them according to their salaries and print out the sorted arraylist in the console

Comment: Can I add files in the question? If so I might add the whole project as .zip file

Comment: Please put question clarifications in the question itself, not in comments. Your question can be edited by clicking the "edit" link.

Answer (score 0):

In your worker class, implement Comparable interface like:

```
public class Worker implements Cloneable, Comparable<Worker> {
....
    public int compareTo(Worker worker) {
        return Double.compare(this.salary, worker.getSalary());
    }
}
```

And then assuming you have list of workers already, you could sort like:

```
Collections.sort(listOfWorkers);
```

clone has nothing to do with sorting the collection or array but you could implement multiple interfaces.